# copy a file using UNC and impersonation

Tags: c#, .net, file-copying

I want to use FileInfo and CopyTo to move some files across a network.  I have to move the files to a share on a server that has to be accessed using a particular user account.  How do I do this - do I have to impersonate that user and then do the copy?

I am using .net 4 and was wondering what the best way accomplish the impersonation is.  I've read about using pInvoke and using advapi32.dll, but I was hoping someone could recommend a better way to do this.

Thanks for any thoughts.

***EDIT***
Thanks for the replies.  This is not a service, it is a console app, but it will be run from multiple machines.  Is there any advantage to using a mapping over using impersonation, or vice-versa?  what is the recommended approach?
I have also considered using a batch file to create the mappings and do the copy, but I wasn't sure how easily it would be to accomplish because the folders to copy from will not always be the same - it will always be within one directory, but the subdirectory name changes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need impersonation all you have to do is to establish a file mapping using the credentials you want to use.  You can accomplish this using either [net use](http://www.dotnet4all.com/dotnet-code/2004/10/how-to-map-network-drive-in-code.html) as a shell out command or [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running as a service, you may need to impersonate. This is not the complete code but the gist of it:

```
     [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern unsafe int FormatMessage(int dwFlags, ref IntPtr lpSource, int dwMessageId, int dwLanguageId, ref string lpBuffer, int nSize, IntPtr* arguments);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);


IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;

            bool isSuccess = LogonUser(username, domain, password, impersonationType, Logon32ProviderDefault, ref token);
            if (!isSuccess)
            {
                RaiseLastError();
            }

            WindowsIdentity newIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(token);
            WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newIdentity.Impersonate();
```

Save the token and then later

```
CloseHandle(token);
```

Comment: If it is a windows service you can run it under required user account. Or create a special account for this service.

Comment: @Den Yes you can. Which does not prevent me from offering an alternative.